# I have a string with "\u00a0", and I need to replace it with "" str_replace fails

Tags: php, encoding, str-replace

I need to clean a string that comes (copy/pasted) from various Microsoft Office suite applications ([Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel), [Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access), and [Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word)), each with its own set of encoding.

I'm using json_encode for debugging purposes in order to being able to see every single encoded character.

I'm able to clean everything I found so far (\r \n) with str_replace, but with \u00a0 I have no luck.

```
$string = 'mail@mail.com\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0;mail@mail.com'; //this is the output from json_encode

$clean = str_replace("\u00a0", "",$string);
```

returns:

```
mail@mail.com\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0;mail@mail.com
```

That is exactly the same; it completely ignores \u00a0.

Is there a way around this? Also, I'm feeling I'm reinventing the wheel, is there a function/class that completely strips EVERY possibile char of EVERY possible encoding?

____EDIT____

After the first two replies I need to clarify that my example DOES work, because it's the output from json_encode, not the actual string!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for me, when I copy/paste your code. Try replacing the double quotes in your `str_replace()` with single quotes, or escaping the backslash (`"\\u00a0"`).

Comment: In your example it works because you are using the output from json_encode not the actual string! If I copy paste my code it works perfectly even for me.

Comment: What happens if you replace `\xa0` rather than `\u00a0`?

Comment: This happens. It does delete the instances of \u00a0 and when printed from json_encode it looks ok, however if i echo the string without json encode I get a � where before there was the \u00a0. At this point I can't understand what's going on.. please give me an explanation! :-)

Comment: I found the solution, just assign the json_encode to a variable and then str_replace like there's no tomorrow. I would love to still understand the gimmick about \xa0 if you may..

Comment: That may be a null character… The escaped character `\u00a0` says "unicode character with hex value 00a0." My original suggestion would have only stripped out the a0 segment. Try replacing \x00a0 with a blank string.

Answer (score 59):

By combining `ord()` with `substr()` on my string containing \u00a0, I found the following curse to work:

```
$text = str_replace( chr( 194 ) . chr( 160 ), ' ', $text );
```

Comment: Thanks! that saved me a lot of time. `"\xc2\xa0"` works as well.

Comment: yep worked for me. I am trying to scrap data from a site which has french text ..

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
$str = str_replace("\u{00a0}", ' ', $str);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thank you. That is the correct notation as per: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double when replacing the Unicode. OP's question was about literal `\u00a0` strings though, but this was what I was after

Comment: This is the unique that worked properly for me.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem. Apparently PHP's json_encode will return null for any string with a 'non-breaking space' in it.

The Solution is to replace this with a regular space:

```
str_replace(chr(160),' ');
```

I hope this helps somebody - it took me an hour to figure out.

Answer (score 4):

This one also works, i found somewhere

```
$str = trim($str, chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0));
```

Comment: What the hell! This is the only answer that worked in my case. Care to explain the solution?

Comment: Don't remember it now :P

Answer (score 3):

A minor point: \u00a0 is actually a non-breaking space character, c.f. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm

So it might be more correct to replace it with " "

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me:

```
$str = preg_replace( "~\x{00a0}~siu", " ", $str );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this with single quotes like this:

```
str_replace('\u00a0', "",$string);
```

Or, if you like to use double quotes, you have to escape the backslash - which would look like this:

```
str_replace("\\u00a0", "",$string);
```

Comment: I ran into this problem as well. Here is the solution that worked for me. I copied a string with the known \u00a0 character into my editor, then copied the 'space' that \u00a0 represents and pasted it into the str_replace function. In the end it looks like this: str_replace(" ","",$string). The space in the first parameter is the non-standard \u00a0. Now run it through json_encode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode($string,  JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE |JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`