# Delete/Filter Characters and or Words from Element in Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, preg-replace

I am trying to delete/filter stray characters/words out of the 'location' portion in my array. So far, doing this outputs the characters I don't want no matter what I do.

Characters I am trying to get rid of: pic\u00a0map

Code:

```
$city = 'Kanosh';
$s = "SELECT * FROM `list` WHERE `city` LIKE '%".$city."%'";
$res = $mysqli->query($s) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$s]");
$a = array(); 
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) { 
$a[] = array(
'title' => $row['title'],
'price' => $row['price'],
'rooms' => $row['rooms'],
'dimensions' => $row['dimensions'],
'location' => preg_replace('pic\u00a0map', '', $row['location']),
'price' => $row['price'],
'address' => $row['address'],
'seller' => $row['seller'],
'href' => $row['href'],
'date' => $row['date']
); 
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($a);
$res->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

Output:

```
[{"title":"Mobile Home Double     Wide","price":"$85000","rooms":"3br","dimensions":"","location":"Kanosh UT     pic\u00a0map","address":"","seller":"real estate - by owner","href":"http:\/\/saltlakecity.craigslist.org","date":"20140811214226"},   {"title":"Mobile Home Double    Wide","price":"$85000","rooms":"3br","dimensions":"","location":"Kanosh UT      pic\u00a0map","address":"","seller":"real estate - by     owner","href":"http:\/\/saltlakecity.craigslist.org","date":"20140811223113"}]
```

Please advise on how to delete/filter/replace characters and or words inside elements of an array.

Comment: Found the answer to the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592502/i-have-string-with-u00a0-and-i-need-to-replace-it-with-str-replace-fails

Comment: as an aside `str_replace` should suffice.

Comment: Yeah the str replace is what i ended up using. Also had to decode unicode characters as listed in my previous commemt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592502/i-have-string-with-u00a0-and-i-need-to-replace-it-with-str-replace-fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found in this thread:

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592502/i-have-string-with-u00a0-and-i-need-to-replace-it-with-str-replace-fails)

For anybody reading this, don't forget about decoding unicode characters. It threw me off.